# Is there an exact solution for $\large\int \frac{dx}{\tan^{-1}(x)}$?

Tags: integration, summation, recreational-mathematics, inverse, trigonometric-integrals

Do you know about the [inverse tangent integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html)? It is defined as:
$$\mathrm{Ti_2(x)=Ti(x)=\int_0^x\frac{tan^{-1}(x)}{x}dx=-\frac1x\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n-1)^2}}$$

Expanding the denominator and then the sum gives many other forms of the function. Also, I wondered what other unsolved trigonometric integrals there are. You can click my [profile questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/905886/tyma-gaidash?tab=questions) to see similar inspiration questions. Here is the function I want to find. Here is an [*interactive graph*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1ksd3hskjh). It is an odd [injective](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) function:

$$\mathrm{T(x)=\int \frac{dx}{tan^{-1}(x)} , \\ T(b)-T(a)=\int_a^b \frac{dx}{tan^{-1}(x)}=\int_{tan^{-1}(a)}^{tan^{-1}(b)} \frac{sec^2(x)}{x}dx\mathop=^{|x|<\frac\pi 2} \quad \int_{tan^{-1}(a)}^{tan^{-1}(b)}\sum_{N=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{N+n}E_{2N}E_{2n}x^{2(N+n)-1}}{(2N)!(2n)!}dx= \quad \sum_{N=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{N+n}E_{2N}E_{2n}(tan^{-1}(b))^{2(N+n)}-(tan^{-1}(a))^{2(N+n)}}{2(2N)!(2n)!(N+n)}}$$

This approach above uses the [Euler numbers $\mathrm E_y$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html) and this [series representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sec/06/01/02/01/0003/). This looks very complicated as I had to multiply the two series together to get a secant squared representation.

Here is a solution for T(x), but I do not know the [Laurent series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) coefficient [formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expansion+1%2Fatan%28x%29-1%2Fx-x%2F3):

$$\mathrm{T(x)=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^{2n-1}dx=\int \frac1x +\frac x3-\frac{4x^3}{45}+\frac{44x^5}{945} -\frac{428x^7}{14175}+\frac{10196x^9}{467775}-\frac{10719068x^{11}}{638512875}+…dx=ln(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_n x^{2n}}{2n}=ln(x)+\frac {x^2}6-\frac{x^4}{45}+\frac{22x^6}{2835}-\frac{108x^8}{28350}+\frac{5098x^{10}}{2338875}-\frac{2679767x^{12}}{1915538625}+…,c_n=1,\frac13,-\frac4{45},\frac{44}{945},-\frac{428}{14175},\frac{10196}{467775},-\frac{10719068}{638512875},…}$$

Here is a graph of T(x). Notice the oblique asymptote which
is a consequence of the fact that $\frac1{\tan^{-1}(\pm \infty)}=\frac2\pi$. The graph is for the area from x=1 to x=$\text x_0$. You can also see the vertical asymptote at x=0 implying infinite area over almost any interval containing x=0:

[image]

Here is motivation using [trigonometric integral functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral). I will assume a primitive here, no constant, for simplicity:

$$\mathrm{\int\frac{dx}{cos^{-1}(x)}=-Si(cos^{-1}(x))}$$

$$\mathrm{\int\frac{dx}{sin^{-1}(x)}=Ci(sin^{-1}(x)}$$

$$\mathrm{\int\frac{dx}{cosh^{-1}(x)}=Shi(cosh^{-1}(x))}$$

$$\mathrm{\int\frac{dx}{sinh^{-1}(x)}=Chi(sinh^{-1}(x)}$$

Just like the actual inverse tangent integral, I wonder if this T(x) function can also be expressed in exact form. If possible, please express in closed form, but an [exact answer](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/decimal-numbers/decimal-numbers.faq.question.467515.html) also works. I would be surprised if T(x) can even be expressed in terms of Ti(x), the inverse tangent integral.

Another answer is to find out if the coefficients I typed above have any pattern that can be written as an mathematical expression.

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Applications:
Try the [inverse integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) theorem on $\tan\frac1x$ You can try this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309701/does-int-11-frac-arctan-x-textarctanh-x-mathrmdx-have-a-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1), find the integral $\mathrm{\int_{i}^{2i}\frac{dx}{tan^{-1}(x)}=\int_1^2\frac{i\,dx}{tanh^{-1}(x)}}$, and I will try to ask a question about the applications though .

Results from @Yuri Negometyanov and @Nikos Bagis show the following results. [*Graphical proof*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ak9xbrxkyr). Note that you can split the sum after distributing the factored numerator. [Bernoulli Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html). Notice the root of the desmos graph at different values. Be sure to set the slider to approach $\pm \infty$ for i by approximation of $\pm 10$ in the graph link:

$$\mathrm{T(x)=\int\frac{dx}{\tan^{-1}(x)}=\frac{x}{\tan^{-1}(x)}+ln\left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)-\frac12 \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n\left(4^n-1\right)B_{2n} \left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)^{2(n-1)}}{(n-1)(2n)!}+C=ln\left(tan^{-1}(x)\right)+\frac{x}{tan^{-1}(x)}-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z}\frac{ln\left(\pi(2n+1)-2tan^{-1}(x)\right)}{(2n+1)^2}+C}$$

I wonder about the integrals of the reciprocal of other inverse trigonometric functions…

Comment: You wrote "$T(x)=\int \frac{dx}{tan^{-1}(x)}=T(b)-T(a)=\int_a^b \frac{dx}{tan^{-1}(x)}$". Make up your mind, you are trying to calculate the indefinite integral or the definite integral.

Comment: @jjagmath these are about the same integrals. If we add bounds to the indefinite integral, we get the definite integral. I only did the one with bounds so I did not have to substitute the bounds back when integrating, and desmos can plot the function in that case. The indefinite integral is my main goal. Do you have any [ideas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309701/does-int-11-frac-arctan-x-textarctanh-x-mathrmdx-have-a-closed?rq=1)?

Comment: Also the FTC, one of them, says that if F(x) is the integral of f(x), then the definite integral from a to b is F(b)-F(a).

Comment: As you have noticed, $T(x)=\int{\sec^2x\over x}\,dx$. I think it very unlikely there's a closed form for this, any more than there is for $\int{\sin x\over x}\,dx$. But there is a theory of *integration in finite terms* which can probably answer the question for certain, and doing a websearch for the italicized phrase will probably get you started on learning about it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In that case, I may change the question into finding an exact solution of the integral. I found one possible form of it. I was thinking more about [the sine integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) which can be expressed in terms of the generalized exponential integral function. There should be a way to evaluate such a simple integrand using any functions in wolfram mathworld or the [functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/) website. Please see equation [(20)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) on the website. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let
$$I(x)=\int\limits_1^x \dfrac{\text dt}{\arctan t},\tag1$$
then
$$I(\tan y)=\int\limits_{\large^\pi/\mspace{1mu}_4}^y\dfrac1t\,\text d\tan t 
\;\overset{\text{IBP}}{=\!=}\;\dfrac{\tan t}t\bigg|_{\large^\pi/\mspace{1mu}_4}^y+\int\limits_{\large^\pi/\mspace{1mu}_4}^y\,\dfrac{\tan t}{t^2}\,\text dt 
= \dfrac{\tan y}y-\dfrac4\pi +\int\limits_{\large^\pi/\mspace{1mu}_4}^y\dfrac{\tan t}{t^2}\,\text dt,\tag2$$
or, applying the known Maclaurin series of the tangent function in the form of
$$\tan t =\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{4^n(4^n-1)\text B_{2n}}{(2n)!}t^{2n-1}= t+\dfrac13\,t^3+\dfrac2{15}\,t^5+\dfrac{17}{315}\,t^7+\dfrac{62}{2835}\,t^9+\dots,\tag3$$

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{I(\tan y)= \dfrac{\tan y}y-\dfrac4\pi+\ln\dfrac{4y}\pi 
+ \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty c_n \left(y^{2n-2}-\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)^{2n-2}\right),}}\tag4$$
where
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{c_n = (-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{4^n(4^n-1)\text B_{2n}}{(2n-2)(2n)!}.}}\tag5$$

I.e., we have got $\;1D\;$ series.

Alternative form of the solution $(4)$ is
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{I(x)= \dfrac x{\arctan x}-\dfrac4\pi+\ln\dfrac{4\arctan x}\pi + \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty c_n\left(\arctan^{2n-2} x -\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)^{2n-2}\right).}}\tag6$$

Comment: [+1] This is a great answer, and I will most likely choose it as the answer to the problem. However, in case another person chooses to answer it, I will leave it here for the next few days. Can you write the final answer in terms of x only? As a final note, please simplify as much as possible. I will check this. Thanks!

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you for the comments. Done.

Comment: Thanks again. Now we have a solution for this type of inverse tangent integral. I am not too sure where this may show up though.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I have a lot of materials and have not articles, and I'm interested too. Try to ask in Academy SE.  Will be glad to know your results.

Comment: You got the accepted answer as you method is simplest and more graphically verified. There were 2 answers, but NikosBagis put more effort even without the extra edits.

Comment: @TymaGaidash And what can I do with my new edition? :)

Comment: Try the [inverse integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) theorem on $\int \tan\frac1x\,dx$ You can try this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309701/does-int-11-frac-arctan-x-textarctanh-x-mathrmdx-have-a-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1), find the integral $\mathrm{\int_{i}^{2i}\frac{dx}{tan^{-1}(x)}=\int_1^2\frac{i\,dx}{tanh^{-1}(x)}}$, and I will try to ask a question about the applications though. Do you know about any applications besides pure math?

Comment: Here are your applications in this [**question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216848/are-there-applications-of-mathrm-int-frac-dxtan-1x).

Answer (score 7):

It is known that
$$
\csc^2 z=\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}\frac{1}{(z-k\pi)^2}\textrm{, }z\neq 0,\pm\pi,\pm 2\pi,\ldots\tag 1
$$
Hence with $z\rightarrow z-\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have
$$
\sec^2 z=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}\frac{1}{(z-\pi/2-k\pi)^2}\tag 2
$$
Also
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int^{\tan t}_{c}\frac{1}{\arctan x}dx=\frac{\sec^2 t}{t}
$$
Hence using (1):
$$
I=\int^{\tan t}_{c}\frac{1}{\arctan x}dx=
$$
$$
=\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } [\frac{4 \pi }{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}+\frac{8 k \pi }{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}-
$$
$$
-\frac{4 \pi  \log(\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}-\frac{8 k \pi  \log(\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}+
$$
$$
+\frac{8 t \log(\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}+\frac{4 \pi  \log(2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}+
$$
$$
+\frac{8 k \pi  \log(2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}-\frac{8 t \log(2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}]+C.
$$
But
$$
S_1=\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}\frac{4\pi}{(\pi+2k\pi)^2(\pi+2 k\pi-2t)}=\frac{\pi  (-t+\tan t)}{2 t^2}
$$
$$
S_2=\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{8 k \pi }{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}=\frac{\pi  t-\pi  \tan t+2 t \tan t}{2 t^2}
$$
$$
S_3=\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{4 \pi  \log (2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}=\frac{\pi  \log(2 t) (-t+\tan t)}{2 t^2}
$$
$$
S_4=\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{8 k \pi  \log(2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}=\frac{\log(2 t) (\pi  t-(\pi -2 t) \tan t)}{2 t^2}
$$
$$
S_5=-\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{8 t \log(2 t)}{(\pi +2 k \pi )^2 (\pi +2 k \pi -2 t)}=\frac{\log(2 t) (t-\tan t)}{t}
$$
Hence
$$
I=S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4+S_5-\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}\frac{4\log(\pi+2k\pi-2t)}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}+C
$$
Hence
$$
\int^{\tan t}_{c}\frac{dx}{\arctan x}=\log(2t)+\frac{\tan t}{t}-\sum_{k\in\textbf{Z},k-odd}\frac{4\log(\pi k-2t)}{\pi^2 k^2}+C\textrm{, }0<t<\frac{\pi}{2}.\tag 3
$$
The logarithm is defined as $\log x:=\{\log x$, $x>0$ and $i\pi+\log(-x)$, when $x<0\}$.
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\arctan x}=\log\left(2\arctan x\right)+\frac{x}{\arctan x}-
$$
$$
-4\sum^{+\infty}_{k=-\infty}\frac{\log\left(\pi (2k+1)-2\arctan x\right)}{\pi^2 (2k+1)^2}+C=
$$
$$
=\log\left(2\arctan x\right)+\frac{x}{\arctan x}
-4\sum^{+\infty}_{k=-\infty}\frac{\log(\left|\pi (2k+1)-2\arctan x\right|)}{\pi^2 (2k+1)^2}+C,\tag 4
$$
where $x>0$.

**Notes.**

This is the graph of $\int^{\tan t}_{\tan 1}\frac{1}{\arctan x}dx$ and the evaluation I found where the sum is trancated at $k=5$

[image]

At $t=e/2$ cutting the sum in $k=100$, we get

[image]

[image]

At $t=e/2$ cutting the sum in $k=1000$, we get

[image]

[image]

This is the graph's of $\int^{t}_{1}\frac{1}{\arctan(x)}dx$ and the evaluations and the evaluation (4):

[image]

[image]

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I have add some numerical results (graphical proof and approximations).

Comment: I see the result working, but this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/55jivn2dkn) shows it slightly off. What does “$k\in \pmb Z,k-\text{odd}$” mean? Please write $k=…-5,-3,-1,1,3,5…$ or $k\in 2\Bbb Z+1$ or $k\in 2z+1, z\in \Bbb Z$. If it does go over the negatives, then complex logarithms are involved in the sum. _You answer looks the simplest which is why I like it._ As your answer is a definite integral, there should be no +C, unless it is the lower bound for tan(c). Finally, please write the final answer in terms of x only like Yuri. Thanks again!

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Ok. I have made the changes. Thank you for your good words.

Comment: Here is your [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1blll6irra). You can see your result is the most elementary one so far, so you may get the bounty. You put in great effort, and you result works. Good job. I will put your answer in the question.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I add two new graph's. Please check them.

Comment: I like the effort, but please see this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mzbl8mwnzw). It seems like desmos cannot handle your answer or I did something wrong. Please click the link and tell me why the two graphs do not match up in quadrant $1$ and $4$? On the other hand, you deserve the bounty, but there were 2 best answers, so Yuri got the accepted answer. Thanks for the help! Note the slider can go to other values.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Thank you very much for the bounty. About desmos, I have add a more convinient version of my formula. I hope will help.

Comment: I owe an apology; Your absolute value version works. [Graphical proof](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q2hfycvtew).

Answer (score 3):

**Long Comment**

Similar idea to @YuriNegometyanov:

$$I(x)=\int\limits_1^x \dfrac{\text dt}{\arctan t}=\int_{\tan ^{-1}(1)}^{\tan ^{-1}(x)} \frac{\tan ^2(u)+1}{u} \, du,\tag1$$

$$I(x)=\int_{\tan ^{-1}(1)}^{\tan ^{-1}(x)} \frac{1}{u} \, du+\int_{\tan ^{-1}(1)}^{\tan ^{-1}(x)} \frac{\tan ^2(u)}{u} \, du,\tag2$$

$$I(x)=\log \left(\frac{16 \tan ^{-1}(x)}{\pi^2 }\right)+x^2 \log \left(\tan ^{-1}(x)\right)-2\int_{\tan ^{-1}(1)}^{\tan ^{-1}(x)}  \log (u) \tan (u) \sec ^2(u) \, du,\tag3$$

The integral in (3) can also be expressed in terms of the infinite series for $\tan u$, since

$$\frac{d^2 \tan (u)}{d u^2}=2\tan (u) \sec ^2(u)=2 \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(2 k-2) (2 k-1) \left(\left(2^{2 k}-1\right) \zeta (2 k)\right) x^{2 k-3}}{\pi ^{2 k}}$$

and

$$\int x^{2 k-3} \log (x) \, dx=\frac{ (2 (k-1) \log (x)-1)}{4 (k-1)^2}x^{2 k-2}$$

Comment: @JamesArathroon Here is my [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vsqrbsvguf) on what seems to be the final answer, but it seems to be a bit off. Either I made a mistake or something else. Notice the summation starting at n=2 for Yuri and that my typed result is at the very bottom of the desmos graph.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer either, but more observations. Consider

$$\int \frac{1}{\tan^{-1}(x)} dx$$

and substitute $x = \tan u$, so $dx = \sec^2 u\ du$. Then

$$\int \frac{1}{\tan^{-1}(x)} dx = \int \frac{\sec^2 u}{u}\ du$$

Now note that $\sec^2 u = 1 + \tan^2 u$ so we can write this as

$$\int \frac{\sec^2 u}{u} du = \int \frac{1}{u}\ du + \int \frac{\tan^2 u}{u}\ du = \ln u + \int \frac{\tan^2 u}{u}\ du$$

Hence, to have a form similar to the ones you've given for $\frac{1}{\sin^{-1}(x)}$ and the like, you'd need to have a new special function for either

$$\int \frac{\sec^2 u}{u}\ du$$

or

$$\int \frac{\tan^2 u}{u}\ du$$

I don't know if these can be solved in terms of

$$\int \frac{\sec u}{u}\ du$$

or

$$\int \frac{\tan u}{u}\ du$$

.

Comment: It would be redundant to define a new function unless academically recognized. Even my “T(x)” function was for fun. Wolfram Alpha refuses to even try to integrate $\frac{\tan^2(x)}x$. Maybe you can find a series expansion for $\sec^2(x)$ or $\tan^2(x)$? Only one series. I used two series as seen above. These are good observations of yours.

Answer (score 0):

This addendum will be for extra ideas found. All answers are pretty much similar and are for fun. [Graphical proof with root at 1.28…](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qg34ubnujk) of @Nikos Bagis’s answer; note that desmos cannot be used to check the hyperbolic version of their answer as it has complex parts.

Note that C can be a complex number because of $\mathrm{ln(tan^{-1}(ix))=\frac{\pi i}{2}+ln(tanh^{-1}(x))}:$

1. $$\mathrm{Th(x)=\int\frac{dx}{tanh^{-1}(x)}=\int\frac{i\,dx}{tan^{-1}(ix)}=\int\frac{2dx}{ln(1+x)+ln(1-x)}=T(ix)=C+\frac{x}{tanh^{-1}(x)}+ln\left(tanh^{-1}(x)\right)+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{4^n\left(4^n- 1\right) B_{2n}\left(tanh^{-1}(x)\right)^{2(n-1)}}{(n-1)(2n)!}=C+ \frac{x}{tanh^{-1}(x)}+ln\left(tanh^{-1}(x)\right)-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{ln\left|\pi(2n+1)-2i\,tanh^{-1}(x)\right|}{(2n+1)^2}}$$

Specific values with expanded logarithms. [A result verification and graph of Th(x) with root at x=$.3…$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/emr1hln342) and [Result verification for last sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284-2sqrt3%29%2Fpi%2Bln%283%29-ln%282%29-4%2Fpi%5E2sum+ln%28abs%281-1%2F%284%283n%2B1%29%29%29%29%2F%282n%2B1%29%5E2+from+-200+to+200). For the graph, note the “i” parameter has to be infinity. Then, one takes a limit as x approaches 1 of the evaluation limits for the sum. This has to be done if an integral bound is 1 as the inverse hyperbolic tangent of 1 is 0 and approaches infinity as a result of the reciprocal and improper integral.

2.$$\mathrm{\int_\frac1{\sqrt{3}}^1\frac{dx}{tan^{-1}(x)}= T\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)-T(1)=\frac{4-2\sqrt3}\pi+ln(3)-\ln(2)-\frac1{2\pi^2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{B_{2n}(-4)^n \pi^{2n}\left(4^n-1\right)\left(4^{2-2n}-6^{2-2n}\right)}{(n-1)(2n)!}= \frac{4-2\sqrt3}\pi+ln(3)-\ln(2)-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{ln\left|1-\frac{1}{4(3n+1)}
\right|}{(2n+1)^2}=.6457455…}$$

3.$$\mathrm{\int_{1-\frac{2}{e+1}}^\frac12 \frac{dx}{tanh^{-1}(x)}=Th\left(1-\frac{2}{e+1}\right)-Th\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{4}{e+1}-\frac1{ln(3)}+ln(ln(3))-2+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_{2n}4^n\left(4^n-1\right)\left(ln^{2n-2}(3)-1\right)}{2^{2n}(n-1)(2n)!}=.0722855…}$$

The other sum representation using @Nikos’s method evaluates to a different constant even with small modifications:

$$\mathrm{ \frac{4}{e+1}-\frac1{ln(3)}+ln(ln(3))-2-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{ln\left|\frac{\pi(2n+1)-i}{\pi(2n+1)-i\, ln(3)}\right|}{(2n+1)^2}\mathop=^{??} .0722855…}$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

> **I wonder what would happen if we expanded and separated the sums…**

Comment: Fixed verification link.